# How do you deploy a container to AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, aws-lambda

I am working on this little project.

https://github.com/jamesgeddes/itsbeginningtolookalotlikechristmas

It's currently a work-in-progress - don't judge!

As you can see, I have configured CircleCI to build, scan and publish the container. That, ideally, should be the end of the road for the Continuous Integration, CI, tool, as Continuous Deployment, CD, should take over, so I would like [Docker Hub Webhooks](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/) to trigger the deployment of that container into AWS Lambda.

Unfortunately, I am struggling to find any dedicated CD tools.

I have seen,

- [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/pricing/overview), but their minimum is £10 per month - more than I would like to pay for such a small project.
- [Harness CD](https://www.harness.io/pricing?module=cd#), but their £0 plan only allows you to deploy to Kubernetes

Everything else appears to be,

- a CI tool
- a CI tool that insists that it can do CD as well
- self-hosted - which I can't be bothered to do for such a small project

How should I go about deploying my container to AWS Lambda while maintaining the best-practice separation of concerns between CI and CD?

Answer (score -1):

The [community edition](https://octopus.com/pricing/overview) of Octopus is free to self-host, so that might be an option if you have somewhere you can run it. You can have 5 targets and 5 projects.

You could run a free cloud trial to test it out and then think about self-hosting once you've worked out the details.

Once you have it, you could use it to deploy other stuff you have, too. I'm using Octopus Cloud community edition to deploy a little monitoring tool I wrote (UpDn) that checks my websites are up, their certificates aren't about to expire, and that my DNS hasn't been messed with. It easily saves me $10 of effort each month :)

Comment: I have seen Octo and don't want to pay or self-host :)

Comment: I'm looking through my list of suggestions, but even the open source stuff would require that you host it as they can't fund this for you (i.e. [Spinnaker](https://spinnaker.io/)). If you don't need all the features of a deployment tool, you may be able to script up your own deployment process to run from your CI tool instead?

Comment: I'll probably just stick with letting Terraform create the lambda based on the latest container in DockerHub